# Plotting a heatmap of temperatures

Tags: python, r, plot, heatmap

I have a matrix of which a smaller version looks like this

```
318.3   318.3   318.3
318.3   318.3   318.3
318.3   318.3   318.3
```

These are the temperatures of a grid of processors. I want to plot a heat map by assigning regular colors i.e. blue to cool and red to hot cores.

An example of what I am looking for is :

[image]

How do I do this using a program or is there any software for linux which does this ?

Comment: if the grid size were small enough, then `image` would do fine. Put in a bigger sample of points

Comment: @42- The actual file is this https://ufile.io/fb6bf Also what is the solution that you are suggesting ?

Comment: Not very much variation in that file. Not looking very useful for demonstration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the `rainbow` palette could be used with `image`

```
m <- matrix(c(1, 1,1,1,1,1,1,
1,2,2,3,2,2,1,
1,2,3,4,3,2,1,
1,2,2,3,2,2,1,
1,1,1,1,1,1, 1), 5,7, byrow=TRUE)

image(m, col=rev(rainbow(100))[ 70:100]) # need to reverse it to have high values red.
```

(The `heatmap` functions generally are dolled-up versions of `image`.)

With the file (that doesn't have much variation) you can get results after reading in the file without a header, removing the column of NA's and coercing to a matrix:

```
 image( f, col=rev(rainbow(350))[ 270:350])
```

[image]

Can also use lattice::levelplot with the obviousl advantage that you get a scale automagically:

```
levelplot(f, col.regions=rev(rainbow(350))[ 270:350])
```

[image]